# Reaching the spesific string

Tags: c

Is there any method that I can reach a specific token in a string? In my code, I used strtok() for the parsing the string token by token but I need to reach the first token, second token, third token etc... to matching each token in a variable (for example, if the first token variable is A then it should be equal to y, if the second token variable is z then it should be equal to w)
Here is my code. There will be some mistakes in my code, sorry for that:

````
    char parsetokens(){
    char string[]="A B(10) < z3";
    char specialchar[] = ":,=+-*/><[]() ";
    char *token = strtok(string,specialchar);

    while (token!=NULL)
    {
        printf ("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok (NULL, specialchar);
    }
for(token=string[0];*token!=0;token++){
    if (token==y)
    {
         var.op=5; //I want to match the first token's variable which is A to the y
    }
    printf ("%s\n",var.op);
}
}  ```
````

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't understand. The question is so clear, minimal and it was checked by the system before the posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strspn` and `strcspn` can be used to iterate through a string and identify tokens delimited by a set of characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {
    char string[]="[A B[x:y] > Z] ";
    char specialchar[] = ":,=+-*/><[]() ";
    char *token = string;
    size_t index = 0;

    while ( *token) {
        token += strspn ( token, specialchar);//count matching characters
        index = strcspn ( token, specialchar);//count non-matching characters
        if ( index) {
            printf ("%.*s at index %d\n"
            , (int)index, token, (int)(token - string));
        }
        token += index;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {
    char string[]="[A B[x:y] > Z] ";
    char item[sizeof string] = "";
    char specialchar[] = ":,=+-/*><[]() ";
    char *token = string;
    size_t index = 0;

    while ( *token) {
        token += strspn ( token, specialchar);//count matching characters
        index = strcspn ( token, specialchar);//count non-matching characters
        if ( index) {
            memmove ( item, token, index);
            item[index] = 0;
            printf ("item: %s\n", item);
            printf ("%.*s at index %d\n"
            , (int)index, token, (int)(token - string));
        }
        token += index;
    }
}
```

Comment: That will solve my problem in a huge way! Many thanks! Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This could be a starting point :

```
int main() {
    char * token = ":,=+-*/><[]()";
    char * string = "A : B : C + D - E << (F)";
    int index;
    int len = strlen(string);
    int tokenCount = strlen(token);
    char tk[2] = {0};
    for (char i=0; i<tokenCount; i++) {
        index = 0;
        tk[0] = token[i];
        char *sub = NULL;
        while (index < len && (sub = strstr(string + index, tk))) {
            index = (sub - string);
            printf("%s at index : %d\n", tk, index);
            index++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
: at index : 2
: at index : 6
+ at index : 10
- at index : 14
< at index : 18
< at index : 19
( at index : 21
) at index : 23
```

Comment: It makes sense! I'll try with this logic, thank you!

Comment: I realized that the incrementation of `index` happened to early so I changed that : the first index found is 2 not 3 (but the incrementation still occur after the print to avoid an infinite loop).

Comment: Yes, I realized that too when I was working, thank you so much. The logic was so close to my question however, in my output the special characters should be excluded. For example if the string is : [A B[x:y] > Z] and the parsed tokens must be like that: A B x y Z. So the parsing index should be like A at index : 1 B at index:3 etc... @dspr